# Issues plotting count distribution displot()

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have count data. I'm trying to document my decision to use a negative binomial distribution rather than Poisson (I couldn't get a quasi-poisson dist. in lme4) and am having graphical issues (the vector is appended to the end of the post).
I've been trying to implement the `distplot()` function to inform my decision about which distribution to model:

here's the outcome variable (physician count):
`plot(d1.2$totalmds)`[image: physician count]

Which might look poisson
[image]
but the mean and variance aren't close (the variance is doubled by two extreme values; but is still not anywhere near the mean)

```
> var(d1.2$totalmds, na.rm = T)
[1] 114240.7
> mean(d1.2$totalmds, na.rm = T)
[1] 89.3121
```

My outcome is partly population driven so I'm using the total population as an offset variable in preliminary models. This, as I understand it, divides the outcome by the natural log of the offset variable so totalmds/log(poptotal) is essentially what's being modeled. Which looks something like:
[image]

But when I try to model this using:
plot 1: `distplot(x = d1.2$totalmds, type = "poisson")`
plot 2: `distplot(x = d1.2$totalmds, type = "nbinomial") # looks way off`
[image]
[image]

plot 3: `plot(fitdist(data = d1.2$totalmds, distr = "pois", method = "mle"))`
plot 4: `plot(fitdist(data = d1.2$totalmds, distr = "nbinom", method = "mle")) # throws warnings`
[image]
[image]

plot 5: `qqcomp(fitdist(data = d1.2$totalmds, distr = "pois", method = "mle"))`
plot 6: `qqcomp(fitdist(data = d1.2$totalmds, distr = "nbinom", method = "mle")) # throws warnings`
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have suggestions for why the following plots look a little screwy/inconsistent?

As I mentioned I'm using another variable as an offset variable in my actual analysis, if that makes a difference.

Here's the vector:
https://gist.github.com/timothyslau/f95a777b713eb33a2fe6

I'm fairly sure NB is better than poisson since `var(d1.2$totalmds)/mean(d1.2$totalmds) # variance-to-mean ratio (VMR) > 1`

But if NB is appropriate the plots should look a lot cleaner (I think, unless I'm doing something wrong with these plotting functions/packages).

Comment: You don't seem to be having problems with your code, but rather with the results. Maybe your question is more fit to Cross Validated? Actually, what do you mean by "crewy/inconsistent"? You provided a lot of examples but I'm not even sure what your question is.

Comment: @molx I think plot 2 is one issue, it doesn't look right. The other is the warnings generated in plot 4 & 6.